# How to get value outside the function in javascript

Tags: javascript

This is my current code in javascript,my problem is that when i click on next button i am able to get temp_x value inside the function, but fails to get value of temp_x value outside. Please help me out where i doing wrong.
I want to get temp_x in [{"x": temp_x}]

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
 data = ["09:15:44.158162924", "09:15:44.244061560", "09:15:44.296753930"]

let temp_x = [];
var Current = 0;


function Next(){
    if(Current == data.length - 1){
        Current = 0;
    }

    else { 
        temp_x.push(data[Current]);
        Current++;
    }

}
<div>
    <button onclick="Next();">Next!</button>
</div>

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  [{ "x": temp_x, "xaxis": "x", "y": ydata, "yaxis": "y"}]
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you are trying to use the variable in different executing context.

`<script></script` each such block creates its own execution context and you are using `let` for assigning a variable which exist inside scope and not available outside of it as it is block scoped.

Use `var` instead `let`

```
var temp_x = [];
var Current = 0;
```

***var*** declarations are globally scoped or function scoped while **let** and **const** are block scoped. **var** variables can be updated and re-declared within its scope; **let** variables can be updated but not re-declared; const variables can neither be updated nor re-declared